# How to position a image in customized section header so that it appears correctly in both the orientations?

Tags: ios

I have a customized section header, in `viewForHeaderInSection`, I have a view and a button on that so it will be like clicking the section header some action will be performed.Now I need an image in the section header so that it changes on clicking the section header.So I added a image view to the view in `viewForHeaderInSection` but the image position is not correct,it is different in landscape and portrait.I need the image in the right corner of the section header.I need to do it immediately.
Please help.
Thanks

```
 -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 /* Create custom view to display section header... */
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];


        UIButton *btn= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
[view addSubview:btn];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(275.0f, 1.5f, 8.0f, 18.0f)];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Selection-Indicator.png"];
        [imageView setImage:image];
        [view addSubview:imageView];
        return view;



}
```

Comment: there is a magical button called "edit" above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oky try this hope this helps u

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
   /* Create custom view to display section header... */
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];

   UIButton *btn= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
   [view addSubview:btn];
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(view.bounds.size.width - 20, 1.5f, 8.0f, 18.0f); //set the offset from right

   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Selection-Indicator.png"];
   [imageView setImage:image];
   [view addSubview:imageView];
   return view;
  }
```

and in rotation handling method u need to reload or update the UI
for example

```
 - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
 {
    //so u dont want to reload the tableview then u can reload the sections 
    // [self.tableVIew reloadData]; //just try this (comment)
    //try this

    NSArray *cells = [self.tableVIew visibleCells];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableVIew indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[cells lastObject]];
    NSIndexSet *set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, totalSectionCount)]; //try by placing the all the section count 
    [self.tableVIew reloadSections:set withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; 
 }
```

Comment: yea it works but sorry...while running in device it takes time to reload and also some memory issues so this is not an efficieent way. Is it possible to set constraints programmatically? but i don't know it didn't work for me..i don't know how to work with constraints programmatically

Comment: then u can reload the sections

Comment: it doesn't work,same problem as before the image is not positioned properly

Comment: how may sections are there in your tableview...?

Comment: @user2523879 u can reload all the sections by this`NSIndexSet *set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, totalSectionCount)];` hear `totalSectionCount` replace by total bumber of sections in your tableview (also edited the code) try it

Comment: @user2523879 after call to this method  `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` u can check weather u are getting call to `viewForHeaderInSection ` once again

Answer (score -1):

You should have something like this:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
[imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(parentView.frame.size.width-50, 5, 30, 30)];
[parentView addSubview:imgView];
```

The sizes in `CGRectMake` are only as an example, but make sure your `UIImageView` is always related to you **parentView.frame.size.width**... that should do it!

EDIT: After your code, you should replace:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(275.0f, 1.5f, 8.0f, 18.0f)];
```

with

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width-15, 1.5f, 8.0f, 18.0f)];
```

play with the **-15** to put the image where you wish...

i hope it helps!

Comment: it's not working,it takes the same frame for both the orientation.

Comment: in portrait it will be correct but when i change the device to landscape the image will be placed somewhere in the middele because the frame is same for both orientations

Comment: try reloading the tableView data when changing the orientation with `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation `